# How does the $z$-component spin operator change while you rotate the Dirac cone

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, quantum-spin, graphene

Normally, we have the $z$-component Pauli matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

For the graphene with a magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is
\begin{align}
\hat{H} = v_{F} \left(\mathbf{P}-e \mathbf{A}\right) \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma},
\end{align}
it has the following commutation relations
\begin{align}
 \left\{\hat{\sigma}_{z},\hat{H}\right\} = 0.
\end{align}
and satisfies the particle-hole symmetry, which is
\begin{align}
 \hat{H}\hat{\sigma}_{z} {\psi} = -\hat{\sigma}_{z}\hat{H} {\psi} = -E\hat{\sigma}_{z} {\psi}.
\end{align}
But if we change the Hamiltonian into
\begin{align}
 H = v_{F} \left(\boldsymbol{P} - e\boldsymbol{A}\right) \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} + \boldsymbol{v}^{\prime} \cdot \left(\boldsymbol{P} - e\boldsymbol{A}\right)  I_{2 \times 2} .
\end{align}
It just like rotates the cone or rotates the z-axis and should also satisfies the particle-hole symmetry with a new operator.

So, what is the new $\hat{\sigma}_{z}$?

Comment: I mean if you see the Fermi surface, the cone is tilted.You can also calculate the dispersion relationship numerically and there is a zero band which is the result of the particle-hole symmetry.